# Problema creando lineas aleatorias en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Hice un programa que crea una linea a partir de dos puntos en posiciones aleatorias en un JFrame. Pero me di cuenta de que cuando minimizaba la ventana y la volvía a maximizar me salía una nueva línea generada por dos puntos distintos a los anteriores. ¿Qué me está saliendo mal?

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    int random1 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
    int random2 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
    int random3 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
    int random4 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
    g.drawLine(random1, random2, random3, random4);
    System.out.println("Random 1: " + random1);
    System.out.println("Random 2: " + random2);
    System.out.println("Random 3: " + random3);
    System.out.println("Random 4: " + random4);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes "mal" es la inicialización de los random dentro de `paint`, cuando se re-dimensiona la GUI implícitamente se hace un llamado a `repaint`, lo que ocasiona que de nuevo todos tus valores aleatorios sean diferentes a los generados antes de minimizar/maximizar y la linea se dibuje en otra zona distinta de la ventana.

Lo que puedes hacer es sacar `int random1`, `int random2`... etc y ubicarlos/inicializarlos en un método diferente a `paint` o hacerlos de ámbito global.

Quiero decir por ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
class Back extends javax.swing.JPanel {
   int random1 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
   int random2 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
   int random3 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
   int random4 = (int) (800 * Math.random());

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     g.setColor(Color.red);
     //int random1 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
     //int random2 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
     //int random3 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
     //int random4 = (int) (800 * Math.random());
     g.drawLine(random1, random2, random3, random4);
     System.out.println("Random 1: " + random1);
     System.out.println("Random 2: " + random2);
     System.out.println("Random 3: " + random3);
     System.out.println("Random 4: " + random4);
   }
}
```

De esta manera cualquier gráfico conservará las ubicaciones iniciales, `repaint` ya no conlleva a regenerar randoms.